# Can't delete metric. error "The metric was modified during the request."

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I want to delete log-based metric programmatically with a cloud functions. I wrote the following script:

```
for metric in client_metric.list_metrics():
    if metric.name not in item_list:
        metric.delete()
        print('delete {}'.format(metric.name))
```

`item_list` contains the list of the metric I don't want to delete.

When testing the function I have the following error:

```
status = StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION 
details = "The metric was modified during the request." 
debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1636482330.781263800","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.20.202:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1069,"grpc_message":"The metric was modified during the request.","grpc_status":9}"
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

ok I need to define the metric before using it like this:

```
    metric = client_metric.metric(
    metric.name
    )
```

Ultimately the code looks like this:

```
for metric in client_metric.list_metrics():
    if metric.name not in item_list:
        metric = client_metric.metric(
        metric.name
        )
        metric.delete()
```

still I'm not sure I understand why it needs to be done like this.

Comment: The code that you wrote in this answer is the solution for your issue?

Comment: yes. why are you asking this?

Comment: just to upvote the answer